# Why are .cshtml changes are not reflected locally until app pool recycle? Why did building my project in Visual Studio stop recycling the app pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web, iis

I'm developing an MVC web app in C#. When I used to save the view (.cshtml) with any basic HTML or CSS changes, I only needed to refresh the page to see my changes. Now, I do not see them reflected locally until I recycle the IIS app pool.

This may be a separate issue, but building the application used to recycle the app pool. Today, when I build the app and test, I do not see any changes to the controllers reflected until I manually recycle the app pool. I know the app pool is not recycled on build because I stay logged in.

I do not know of any changes made to the project. It is possible another team member changed something. What could have changed? Where should I check first?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that your browser isn't caching the site such that you won't see small changes? This is where I would check first. I've noticed that most of the time when I am not seeing my changes it has to do with the browser caching my site so that I don't see my changes.

Typically I avoid this issue by:

- Opening the developer tools in the browser
- Disable caching,
- Refresh,
- (optionally) Enable it again if you must have caching enabled to test your changes.

One thing to note is if your DLLs aren't changing on a build, or IIS is not detecting changes in the files it is hosting then it won't automatically recycle the app pool. However this doesn't sound like the issue you are having since you say you're expecting changes in the controllers.

It sounds unlikely, but not impossible, that another team member changed a setting that would affect IIS. You may be able to check your configuration settings for IIS but it is more likely the issue is with caching in the browser.

Comment: This would be a good start. I would be surprised if changes to the controllers were not picked up, but certainly the site.css file is cached in Firefox at least.

Comment: @Lydia, I have made sure it isn't caching. The primary way I've been doing this has been with developer tools, right clicking the refresh icon and selecting "empty cache and hard reload."

Answer (score 1):

Someone on the team added fcnMode="Disabled" to our httpRuntime tag in the web.config. Removing it locally has fixed the problem I've been experiencing.

We are discussing internally why it was added and how to move forward.